# Is there a term for it when you use an obviously false statement to highlight the falsity or absurdity of another?

Tags: terminology, logic

For example, person A states something. Person B says "And pigs fly" to imply person A was wrong.

If there's no term for it, what could you call that that sounds smart?

Comment: It's called sarcasm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *diasyrmus*, which, according to the [Silva Rhetoricae definition](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/D/diasyrmus.htm) is "[r]ejecting an argument through ridiculous comparison."

In this case the comparison is implied:  person A's statement is as false or absurd as the notion of flying pigs.

Comment: The meaning of this word is spot-on, although it's so obscure I'm not sure how usable it would be in practice.

Comment: Well, you can use its obscurity to your advantage when searching for a remark that "sounds smart." :)

Answer (score 8):

To a logician, your examples would be *reductio ad absurdum*.  "If that's true, then I'm a Dutchman/the Queen" is both a well-attested phrase and a valid proposition, implying that whatever it is is false.  Similarly, "And pigs fly" asserts the equivalency of what has just been said to a clearly absurd proposition.  (Martin Gardner, in *The Annotated Snark*, traces the phrase to "an old Scottish saying, 'Pigs may fly, but it isn't likely'.")

Comment: Also called the absurd consequences move.

Answer (score 5):

A general word for such a response is [**retort**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/retort), before which you can use a relevant adjective if necessary.

You could call the above, for instance, a *sarcastic* or *witty retort*. (Though I think you'd have to do a bit better than "and pigs fly" to merit the word witty.)

Another option is [**riposte**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/riposte?__utma=1.67300372.1316441212.1317539771.1317539816.37&__utmb=1.2.10.1317539816&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1317539771.36.20.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=influenceable&__utmv=-&__utmk=268618097).

I should add that neither retorts nor ripostes need be "false" themselves. They do, however, highlight the falsity or absurdity of what was just said.

Comment: "O Sir, we quarrel in print, by the book, as you have books for good manners. I will name you the degrees. The first, the Retort Courteous; the second, the Quip Modest; the third, the Reply Churlish; the fourth, the Reproof Valiant; the fifth, the Countercheck Quarrelsome; the sixth, the Lie with Circumstance; the seventh, the Lie Direct." *As You Like It* V, 4